# rest api code for connect wordpress database with application

Tags: api

I'm new in wordpress and I try to get data by rest API for my mobile app. But I have a problem for getting products by category. I used WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library and wc-api-php but I couldn't find any thing.

in this DOC woocommerce-rest-api-docs I found this Limit result set to products assigned a specific category, e.g. ?category=9,14. but still nothing.

I even change my permalink many time. I use last version of wordpress and woocommerce.

I also used filter but still nothing. Maybe I used them in wrong way but i tried to be like DOC.

Answer (score 0):

please use this plugin The WordPress REST API exposes
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am already used this plugin...but i want the code..not online api link for access database

Answer (score 0):

```
   $sql_str = "SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts p inner join wp_term_relationships tr on tr.object_id = p.ID inner join wp_terms t on t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND t.slug = 'tamil-sports' order by p.ID DESC";
//Enter category name on t.slug
//eg:t.slug = 'tamil-sports'
   //t.slug = 'english-sports'
```